# No matching signal for On_actionCapture_triggered

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, face-detection

I am trying to show on screen live feed from a camera that will show detected faces. However I keep getting:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for On_actionCapture_triggered()
```

I have coded this with out using the GUI to link any slots or signals. I don't understand where the issues lies.

The program runs and then error displays in the Application output box.

Any insight as to where the issue is would be appreciated.

The .h file is

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>


namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_actionCapture_triggered();

private:
    Ui::Dialog* _ui;
    CvCapture*      _capture;
    IplImage*       _img;
    CvHaarClassifierCascade* _cascade;
    CvMemStorage*   _storage;
    QList<CvScalar>  _colors;
    QPixmap*         _pixmap;
    QTimer*          _timer;

};
```

The cpp file is:

```
#endif // DIALOG_H

#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cvaux.h"

#include <QTimer>


Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
_ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    _ui->setupUi(this);
    _capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
    _cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
    _storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    _colors << cvScalar(0.0,0.0,255.0) << cvScalar(0.0,128.0,255.0)
            << cvScalar(0.0,255.0,255.0) << cvScalar(0.0,255.0,0.0)
            << cvScalar(255.0,128.0,0.0) << cvScalar(255.0,255.0,0.0)
            << cvScalar(255.0,0.0,0.0) << cvScalar(255.0,0.0,255.0);

    _timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_actionCapture_triggered()));
    _timer->start(10);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    cvReleaseImage(&_img);
    cvReleaseCapture(&_capture);
    delete _ui;
}

void Dialog::on_actionCapture_triggered()
{
    // Query camera for next frame
    _img = cvQueryFrame( _capture );

    if (_img)
    {
        // Detect objects
        cvClearMemStorage( _storage );

        CvSeq* objects = cvHaarDetectObjects(_img,
                                         _cascade,
                                         _storage,
                                         1.1,
                                         3,
                                         CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                         cvSize( 100, 100 ));

        int n = (objects ? objects->total : 0);

        CvRect* r;
        // Loop through objects and draw boxes
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );
            cvRectangle( _img,
                         cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
                         cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                         _colors[i%8]
                        );
        }

        // Convert IplImage to QImage
        QImage image = QImage((const uchar *)_img->imageData,
                              _img->width,
                              _img->height,
                              QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
        _pixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        _ui->labelCapture->setPixmap(*_pixmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt [autoconnect mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) tries to connect signals to slots of objects with the form of:

```
void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
```

So here it tries to find an object with the name `actionCapture` which has a signal with the name of `triggered` to connect it to your slot. But there is no such a thing and it outputs that warning.

You should change the name of your slot to some other name to avoid this warning.